# react material-table is not showing calendar icon while editing date field. Is there a way to add calendar icon

Tags: material-ui, material-table

react material-table is not showing calendar icon while editing date field. Is there a way to add calendar icon?
for date field i have taken the type as "date" and "datetime"
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-hertz-v5x2o
[image: no calendar icon]

Comment: try to change the textfield type by `type="datetime-local"` [sandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-06ebd).

Comment: Thank you for your comments however material-table do not support type="datetime-local". so we can use either with date or datetime. May be just because of that it's not showing the icon. Can we customize it. I tried all the pickers however it's not icon for any tried option